# OpenCV 4.2.0 FileStorage segmentation fault

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault

[This is a repost of [this](https://answers.opencv.org/question/225841/420-filestorage-crash-on-getnodeptr-segmentation-fault/) question on the OpenCV Q&A forums.]

Hi! I'm having a big issue with the FileStorage API with [this YML file (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/UAAdGjP1) (and any other YML I throw at OpenCV). Basically, any time I try to access information on any `FileNode`, the program segfaults.

At first, I though it was due to my custom OpenCV build on macOS, but after trying with the pre-built OpenCV 4.2.0 Windows binaries, the problem persists.

Messing around in LLDB i figured that the crash happens in

`cv::FileStorage::Impl::getNodePtr(unsigned long, unsigned long)`

The relevant code segment is:

```
cv::FileStorage fs;
try{
    fs = cv::FileStorage("someFile.yml", cv::FileStorage::READ);
}catch(cv::Exception ex)
{
    return 1;
}

cv::FileNode node = fs.root();

std::cout << "Got root node" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Root node is type: " << node.type() << std::endl; //Crash here
```

I'm really at a loss... any help is appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

On the opencv forums, someone found out that initializing `fs` in the `try/catch` block caused the issue. Initializing it outside of it, as in `cv::FileStorage fs = cv::FileStorage("someFile.yml", cv::FileStorage::READ);` solves the problem. I still have no idea why this happens...

Answer (score 1):

As written in the OpenCV Q&A answer, this issue can be circumvented like this:

```
cv::FileStorage fs;
try{
    fs.open("someFile.yml", cv::FileStorage::READ);
}catch(cv::Exception ex)
{
    return 1;
}

//Do stuff with fs
```

I'm not into the expert c++ stuff (copy constructors and stuff), but probably my issue had something to do with that...