# Segmentation fault when loading YML file with cv::FileStorage in ROS

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault, yaml, ros

I have a problem with `cv::FileStorage` when I tried to read a YML file in a ROS node. I got `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error when running the node and I was able to identified the problem which comes from the calling of `cv::FileStorage` constructor. Then, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60091356/opencv-4-2-0-filestorage-segmentation-fault) similar question, I put the following code in main function (separately in a node), but the error still occurs, due to the `fs.open(...)` function.

Remark that I linked the necessary packages with my ros package, and I provided the absolute path to the file as well.

```
std::string filePath = "/home/user/catkin_ws/src/arucov3_node/param/raspicam_v2_400x300.yml";
cv::FileStorage fs;
try{
    fs.open(filePath, cv::FileStorage::READ);
}
catch(cv::Exception ex){
    ROS_ERROR("%s", ex.what());
    return 0;
}
```

For providing more information about this issue, I tried to debug with gdb and got the detailed error message:

> `Thread 1 "detect_node" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x00007ffff51e4a18 in cv::FileStorage::Impl::release(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*) [clone .constprop.330] ()`

Hope someone could help me for this problem.

Comment: *I linked the necessary packages with my ros package* -- That error suggests that you didn't do this  I have not done ROS, but an error with such basic code, and having an issue with an internal function called `release` suggests a version mismatch of packages in some way.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comment. I am gonna check the version of the linked OpenCV library.

Comment: The sign that something isn't installed correctly or a mismatch somewhere is when you have a very simple program that should build and run, but you get errors in some obscure internal function.  Looks like this is what's happening in your case (again, not sure, since I haven't done ROS programming).

Comment: Yes, based on your observation, I tried to specify OpenCV version as 3.2.0, and it works. I used OpenCV 4.5.2 which was built from source, and didn't work. It's so strange that a newer version doesn't work on such a basic utility function.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer.  You know more about this than I do (even though it had all the earmarks of a setup issue).

Comment: Yes, I just did that. Thanks a lot for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out this issue based on PaulMcKenzie's comments. It was a version problem of OpenCV. Actually, aside from binary installed OpenCV 3.2.0 in Ubuntu, I have built OpenCV 4.5.2 from source, with which my program is linked and didn't work.

So I specify in *CMakeLists.txt*: `find_package(OpenCV 3.2.0 REQUIRED)`
Then it is working.

I felt so strange about that a newer version of OpenCV doesn't work with such a basic function. Not sure if it was me who have missed anything.

I update my response by giving more details:

The 4.5.2 version of OpenCV didn't work for some reasons, so I rebuilt it by cloning the 3.4 branch of [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv). (The default 3.2.0 version in Ubuntu lacks some of the latest functionalities)

Since I have built my package (and also another library from source) based on OpenCV 4.5.2, I need to rebuild everything giving the path to the same version of OpenCV. Basically it was simply adding an argument while compiling by cmake or catkin, like `cmake -DOpenCV_DIR=<pathTo-OpenCVConfig.cmake> ..`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's related to your issue without seeing the rest of your code, but OpenCV exceptions are not copyable, so your catch won't work. Try this, you might have an actual error message instead:

```
catch(const cv::Exception& e){
    ROS_ERROR("%s", e.what());
    //... abort or continue
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the program is not even able to reach `catch(...)`, I got segmentation fault error on the line `fs.open(filePath, cv::FileStorage::READ);`

Answer (score 0):

i also have this probelm. Well, after reading your comments and answer, i found that's because opencv version mismatch. you can use command below to find which .so with problem.

```
ldd ./your_binary | grep opencv
```

i think you misuse version 3.2 and 4.5, in ros, that may be caused by cv_bridge, so, make sure all you library have same version.